# Devise Model does not allow Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I recently downloaded and installed Devise for Rails 4. I used it on the model "actors"; which have a subset model called "employee"

For the class "Actor"

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

include UUIDHelper

has_one :access, autosave: true
has_one :employee, autosave: true
has_many :contact_detail, autosave: true
has_many :file_set
has_many :link_set

mount_uploader :logo, AvatarUploader
validates :name, uniqueness: true
validates_presence_of :name
validates_length_of :description, maximum: 256

def actor_name
  actor.name
end

validates :logo,
          :file_size => {
              :maximum => 25.megabytes.to_i
          }

end
```

For the class "Employee"

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
include UUIDHelper
belongs_to :actor
has_one :status
has_many :restdays
has_one :regular_work_period

validates_presence_of :actor
end
```

I previously had this relation unto a view:

```
<td><%= employee.actor.name %></td>
```

Now it spews out an error:

undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

What did I do wrong? Did Devise do something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error indicates this employee object doesn't have actor. `employee.actor` outputs nil.

Just check your employee object is loaded correctly. It is not a Devise problem.